# How to group custom posts in admin menu based off taxonomy/postmeta

Tags: custom-post-types, taxonomy

I created a custom post type named `cars` and I am trying to find a way to display the posts in my admin menu where it will group the posts based off either taxonomy or postmeta by car manufacturers, then displaying each post (or car make) with that taxonomy or postmeta under it.

Like this:

```
- BMW (either taxonomy group or postmeta)
-- X1 (post)
-- X2 (post)
-- X3 (post)
-- X4 (post)
-- X5 (post)
-- X6 (post)

- Ford (either taxonomy group or postmeta)
-- Escape (post)
-- Mustang (post)
-- Explorer (post)
-- GT40 (post)
-- Focus (post)

- Pontiac (either taxonomy group or postmeta)
-- Grand Am (post)
-- Trans Am (post)
-- Sunfire (post)
-- Aztec (post)
-- Bonneville (post)
```

I'd like to try and make so that it's easier to manage post (car models) by grouping them by their manufactures, versus having a running list of a cars.

Any thoughts or direction to start would be much appreciated.

Comment: try this to add a new page in admin : https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_menu_page/

Comment: The plugin Admin Columns can handle a lot of this, might be worth checking out: https://wordpress.org/plugins/codepress-admin-columns/